# Android Scrollview and layout problems

Tags: android-layout

I have a question regarding android layouts. I cannot achieve what I am looking for and I need some direction.
I am looking for a layout that will be inside a Scroll View layout. its hard to explain but a picture is worth thousand words.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qep9E.png)

I want this inside a scroll view, can any help please?

Comment: Do you want the image views inside a scroll view? Or, the whole Layout inside a scroll view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to add images dynamically than this is the layout you want Try this.

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgView1"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgView2"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/imgView1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgView3"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/imgView2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgView4"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/imgView3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linImages"></WebView>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here i am attaching screenshot of this layout UI.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,I have made two layouts ..

**1) activity_main** that contains gridview and webview.

**2)activity_gridview** which contains imageview which will inflate in gridview.

I have added images dynamically to Gridview using BaseAdapter.

In MainActivity i have set that Adapter to GridView. Try this code once.

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linImages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/grid"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:numColumns="1"></GridView>

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linImages"></WebView>
        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_gridview.xml :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/star2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/star1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/star3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/star1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomAdapter.java :**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int flags[];
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] flags) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.flags = flags;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return flags.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.activity_gridview, null);
        ImageView imgView1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgView1);
        ImageView imgView2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgView2);
        ImageView imgView3 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgView3);
        ImageView imgView4 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgView4);

        imgView1.setImageResource(flags[0]);
        imgView2.setImageResource(flags[1]);
        imgView3.setImageResource(flags[2]);
        imgView4.setImageResource(flags[3]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int images[] = {R.drawable.star2, R.drawable.star1, R.drawable.star3, R.drawable.star1};
    GridView grid;
    CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), images);
        grid.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
}
```